# Why it takes different times to run same program?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I was trying to run a deep learning code in which the test data contains 100 images. Each time I do the testing, it takes different time for the algorithm to run even though the order in which the images are processed is same. I thought that it is due to the random initialization of weights. Later, I tried to run a program which uses opencv(without deep learning). When I ran that multiple times, I noticed that it also takes different time to process even though the images are processed in the same order.

My question is : Why is it taking different time to run the same program which takes images as input even though the images are processed in the same order each time?

Also, for deep learning codes, is it taking different time due to the random initialization of weights?

Comment: How much is the variation, and how are you measuring it?

Comment: Some seconds difference are there. I am printing the time taken in the terminal using tic toc in python.

Comment: That sounds normal, and no, its not because of random weight initialization, there are many sources of entropy that contribute to that, specially the scheduler, interrupts, and any other software you might be running.

Comment: Why the timing difference is there when using opencv?

Comment: Its the same reason as any other software, mostly process scheduling and non real time operating systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a lot of factors of why this is happening. Also it would be good how big the relative time difference is. Are we talking about 5% or 50%?

Since you experience this in both cases (deep learning and opencv) I would guess it is one of the following.

Does something else run on the machine where you run the code. Is there difference in load? So check if something is using the cpu and gpu (if you use the gpu yourself).

You probably load the images from the file system. Depending on the medium they are stored on (HDD, SDD, over network ...) it can have quite a big impact on runtime. If you run the code multiple times in a row does the time change, maybe get lower? That could mean it is the file system access.